# Get the number of rows of a csv file from a url?

Tags: node.js, csv

I have a link say "http://www.example.com/01.csv" I would like to get the number of rows in the file 01.csv before downloading the entire file.

I am streaming the rows one by one using request npm module if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the server does not support it, then it is impossible.

Even if you have a file on the disk, it is impossible without reading the whole.